# How do I disable autoplay on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

When I go to a YouTube video, the video is automatically started, and I hate this. How do I disable the auto-play feature?

Answer (score 11):

**Google Chrome:**

For users of Google Chrome, you can use the extension [Stop Autoplay](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgdfnbpkmkkdhgidgcpdkgpdlfjcgnnh?hl=en-GB) for YouTube. This extension will automatically turn off, disable and disable auto-play feature on YouTube, however this extension will not disable buffering.

Comment: The extension is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you from the beginning of hopefully can help

1. Visit the YouTube website (youtube.com).
2. Log in to your YouTube account.
3. Click your account's pull-down menu, and then click "My Videos" to see a list of your YouTube video playlists.
4. Click on a playlist. A page will open, showing a list of the videos in the playlist.
5. Click on "Play All." The playlist tool bar will appear at the bottom of the page.
6. Hover your mouse over the "Autoplay" button, which has two curved arrows forming a circle. A message will appear, saying "Turn Autoplay Off." Click on the "Autoplay" button to turn the autoplay feature off. Click it again to enable it.

Comment: I don't have "My Videos" in the menu, so these instruction don't really work (though you can get to that button from any playlist anyway). Also, what you describe is a different "autoplay" which means the auto-advancement of the playlist. What it will do is stop the playlist from auto-playing the next song in the list, this is not the same as stopping every video on youtube from auto-playing.

Comment: It is a way to disable auto play youtube

Comment: @ChuzeinPartII That method only disables playlist auto-playing. Not disabling it globally on every video without a playlist.

Answer (score 1):

With **Firefox** you can use [YouTube Control Center](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-control-center/) open source add-on to configure autoplay behavior and much more.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Greasemonkey [script](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/12008) for it, works very well.

Answer (score 0):

In **Firefox**, the excellent [Flashblock extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) (which will also hide tons of obnoxious ads) can be used to create a simple clickable icon out of any Flash videos. Just don't whitelist youtube.com, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this user script: [YouTube Auto Buffer & Auto HD & Remove Ads](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49366). It lets you disable autoplay, and also choose whether the video should buffer when the page loads. (The script also supports four other features, all about changing the playback settings of a video when you load its page.)

If you haven’t installed a user script before, they’re like browser extensions, but they depend on another browser extension to run. In Firefox, use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/); in Chrome, per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/578288), either install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) or drag the `.user.js` file into the Extensions tab.

Comment: As of May 2019, this script no longer seems to work

Answer (score 0):

For Pale Moon and Firefox the [FlashStopper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashstopper/) add-on does the job.

Source: [https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?t=11167](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashstopper/)

Answer (score 0):

At the top right of a YouTube video page, there is an "Autoplay" switch, but that's not sufficient. On the channels' "Home" tab, there still may be a trailer video that plays automatically.

Quoting this [question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/3zc0k6/can_i_stop_the_video_in_a_channels_home_tab_from/?st=j1tx8a20&sh=7d0e4dbc):

> Can I stop the video in a channels 'Home' tab from automatically playing?
>
> I just find it really irritating that a video starts playing when I visit a channel. I find myself quickly clicking the 'Videos' or 'Playlists' tab before the video in the 'Home' tab has a chance to start.

And this answer:

> If you subscribe to the channel, the trailer will not autoplay. The point of the auto playing trailer for non-subbed visitors is to quickly introduce them to the channel.

I feel manipulated like a sheep, and video autoplay is one of the most irritating thing ever. Knowing they do it on purpose grinds my gears.

I'll have to investigate for a solution, preferably without installing a 17514th Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

Recently with Youtube fully updating to HTML5 players, they completely removed the autoplay button from the YouTube playlist. I tried all extensions promising to disable the autoplay button, and none of them worked with the latest updates from YouTube, except for this extension:

1. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cafckninonjkogajnihihlnnimmkndgf Disable HTML5 Autoplay (Reloaded) Offered by: totallzero

> Disable autoplay and preloading of HTML5 video and audio players.
>   “Disable HTML5 Autoplay (Reloaded)” disables HTML5 audio and video autoplaying.
>
> Now any video is blocked until you click the agreement button.
>   In addition to removing the HTML autoplay attribute from media elements, “Disable HTML5 Autoplay (Reloaded)” also hooks into the media's JavaScript API. This allows for restrictions on media control and simulation of expected behavior to ensure that all pages behave normally. Main and most requested feature: this blocker has a customizable white list, so you may add your favorite sites to exclude from blocking autoplay. To deactivate a function, simply uncheck the related item from toolbar-panel. With this extension you will never have to worry about videos auto playing in the background. In addition, the video will be automatically buffered if necessary. 7c0d349f